# Groovy Generics with Class as a Argument

Tags: generics, groovy, reflection

I am trying to create a helper method in Groovy for my spock test and getting compiler error. Listed below is the code

```
ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Object>> createResponseEntityPagedResources(String jsonString, Class clazz){
    ResponseEntity<PagedResources<clazz>> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(new PagedResources<clazz>(jsonString, new PagedResources.PageMetadata(1, 0, 0)), HttpStatus.OK)
    return responseEntity
}
```

Error is

> Can not resolve symbol clazz

Answer (score 0):

Consider for example this snippet:

```
ResponseEntity<PagedResources<clazz>>
```

clazz must be a type parameter (this will not be present at runtime). But here it is a real value of type Class.